# Connected hard drive with ubuntu server on windows 10, displays as raw

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, filesystems, mount

A 500GB hard drive that has Ubuntu Server installed got connected to another computer that is run by Windows 10 on an SSD. I want to be able to view the hard drive's contents at all times while on Windows 10. Disk Management shows no filesystem and of course assigns no letter. I used [ext2fsd](https://www.google.gr/search?q=ext2fsd&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=DVHYV827Fs3DaKGVgGA) tool, the partition with the data is displayed as RAW while the Grub partition is displayed as ext2 and can be properly mounted. What can I do to achieve my goal

P.S. I can always boot into the Ubuntu Server OS to display any information you might need regarding the partitions and what so.

[Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDwVX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DiskInternals has a free [Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/). You could put a shortcut to it in the *Startup* folder. It has the merits of being read-only (since Windows is not necessarily to be trusted writing to ext*n* file partitions).

Comment: I did find Linux Reader before I saw the answer. It's not exactly what I need though because in order to open the files (some are executables too) i first need to "save" them to the SSD.